# d3 zoom behaviour is overwriten by mousemove event

Tags: d3.js, svg

I am implementing d3.js zoom behaviour on a svg, on the same svg I also need to capture mouse coordinate so I can set position of a tool tips that follow mouse cursor's position.

The problem is that my 'mousemove' event has override d3.js zoom behaviour.
With 'mousemove' event added, zoom behaviour stop working.

It is either I have 'mousemove' event or 'zoom' event, but not both. Any suggestion how to get around this? Thanks.

```
    // bind zoom behavior
    selection_svg.call(
        d3.behavior.zoom()
        .translate([0, 0])
        .scale(1)
        .scaleExtent([1, 14])
        .on('zoom', ()=>{ selection_plotArea.attr('transform', 'translate('+d3.event.translate+')scale('+d3.event.scale+')'); })
    );

    // tool tip coordinate
    const toolTipNode = selection_toolTip.node();
    toolTipNode.style.position = 'absolute';
    selection_svg.node().addEventListener('mousemove',function(evt){
        const coord_client = {
            x:evt.clientX,
            y:evt.clientY,
        }
        toolTipNode.style.left = `${coord_client.x}px`;
        toolTipNode.style.top = `${coord_client.y}px`;
    }, false);
```

I have added the code for this problem to fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/apollotang/rt9t1vdj/

Comment: could you add a jsfiddle representing your problem?

Comment: @Saeed, I added the fiiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/apollotang/rt9t1vdj/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be related to `tooltipNode` catching mouse events. By adding some offset to `coord_client` your problem would be gone.

```
  selection_svg.on('mousemove', function () {
    const coord_client = {
      x: d3.event.layerX + 10,
      y: d3.event.layerY + 10
    };
    toolTipNode.style.left = `${coord_client.x}px`;
    toolTipNode.style.top = `${coord_client.y}px`;
  }, false);
```

*Note*: I also changed `clientX` and `clientY` to `layerX` and `layerY` since there was a bug when scrolling changed mouse position and `tooltipNode` would have been separated from mouse. Besides the event handling code changed to be handled by d3.

Comment: Yes @Saeed, tooltipNode is blocking triggering of event on svg underneath. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a mousemove event attached to your svg, be sure you aren't calling d3.event.stopPropagation() within the mousemove event, or else you will prevent the zoom behavior.